# Transform Object in Array Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an Object:

```
Object{
         "field1":"fill this field!",
         "field1":"fill this field!",
         "field1":"fill this field!"
}
```

I need to access the key and value of this Object.
How can I transform this Object in Array to use forEach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to "transform" it, you can loop on the keys directly.

```
Object.keys(yourObject).forEach( key => {
     console.log(yourObject[key]); //value    
     console.log(key); //key
});
```

Comment: Doing this I get the value ok? And how can I get the key?

Comment: You have the key in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the object's keys and place the values in a new array.

```
  const _versions = [];
  Object.keys(versions).forEach(v => _versions.push(versions[v]));
  this.versions = _versions;
```